# How does SIM unlocking work under the hood?

Tags: sim-unlocking, partitions

I know what SIM unlocking is and how to do it, but my question is how does SIM unlocking work under the hood? What is actually going on that prevents me from just popping another carriers SIM in there?

More importantly, since many of us have root access, unlocked bootloaders, and S-OFF for the HTC folks why are there no easy "flash this ROM\file and unlock your phone" scenarios?  Is the locking mechanism physically present on the Qualcomm chip and not actually part of the Android system? I would think it would be in the radio partition or EFS.